# How to use Scala varargs from Java code

Tags: java, scala, console, scala-java-interop

There are plenty of articles on calling Java varargs from Scala code, but the only thing I could find the opposite way round was this question: [Using scala vararg methods in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309480/using-scala-vararg-methods-in-java), which doesn't have any concrete examples.

I'm trying to use `scala.Console` from some Java code, for the reason that `java.io.Console` doesn't work in Eclipse, whereas the Scala one does. But I cannot get the method

```
def readLine (text: String, args: Any*): String
```

to work because it seems to be expecting a `scala.collection.Seq[Any]` for the second argument, and I don't see how to create a  `Seq` in Java. How can I work around this?

Things I've tried:

1) Using null

```
// Java
String s = scala.Console.readLine("Enter text: ", null);
```

- get rewarded with a `NullPointerException`.

2) Replacing the `null` with `scala.collection.Seq.empty()`, but javac reports all sorts of errors such as `Seq` not having an `empty` method.

3) Using the `Nil` object in the `scala.collection.immutable` package object, but the syntax suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553173/how-to-access-an-object-foo-contained-in-a-scala-package-object-from-java), which would be `scala.collection.immutable.package$Nil$.MODULE$`, but that can't be resolved.

Of course I could just use the `readLine()` method that doesn't take varargs, but that would be too easy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use:

```
scala.collection.Seq$.MODULE$.empty();
```

from Java code to create an empty sequence. Otherwise, you can use:

```
new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer();
```

to create an empty array buffer into which you can then add elements and use it as an argument to Scala vararg methods.

Otherwise, if you design a Scala library with vararg methods which you want to use from Java code, then use the `varargs` annotation. It will generate a Java version of the method which takes an array instead of a `Seq`.

```
scala> class A {
     |   @annotation.varargs def foo(x: Int*) { println(x) }
     | }
defined class A

scala> println(classOf[A].getMethods.toList)
List(public void $line1.$read$$iw$$iw$A.foo(scala.collection.Seq), public void $line1.$read$$iw$$iw$A.foo(int[]), ...)
```

Above, reflection shows that there are 2 versions of method `foo` generated - one that takes a `Seq[Int]` and another which takes an `int[]`.

Comment: Great, that works. Both still show errors in Eclipse, but they do actually compile. This might have been part of the problem.