# Spark's Column.isin function does not take List

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to filter out rows from my Spark Dataframe.

```
val sequence = Seq(1,2,3,4,5)
df.filter(df("column").isin(sequence))
```

Unfortunately, I get an unsupported literal type error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

according to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#isin%28scala.collection.Seq%29) it takes a scala.collection.Seq list

I guess I don't want a literal? Then what can I take in, some sort of wrapper class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@JustinPihony's answer is correct but it's incomplete. The `isin` function takes a *repeated parameter* for argument, so you'll need to pass it as so :

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)).toDF("column")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column: int]

scala> val sequence = Seq(1,2,3,4,5)
// sequence: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val result = df.filter(df("column").isin(sequence : _*))
// result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column: int]

scala> result.show
// +------+
// |column|
// +------+
// |     1|
// |     2|
// |     3|
// |     4|
// |     5|
// +------+
```

Comment: this also helped me understand what was going on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala

Comment: It's all in the Scala Language Specification. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the underlying [Scala implementation uses `varargs`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column), so the documentation in Java is not quite correct. It is using the `@varargs` annotation, so you can [just pass in an array.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10061468/779513)