# How to convert Array[String] to String* in scala with spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I hava a `RDD` and a `Array[String]`,I want to convert `RDD` to `DataFrame`,the `Array[String]'`s value are colnames,but `DataFrame.toDf()` function need a `String*` type

this is toDF()'s source code:

```
    def toDF(colNames: String*): DataFrame = ds.toDF(colNames : _*)
```

this is my code:

```
 val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val arr=Array(
      (1,2),
      (3,2),
      (4,2),
      (5,2),
      (7,2)

    )
    val colNames=Array("first","second")
    val df = sc.parallelize(arr,2).toDF("??","??")
```

this is my expect result:

```
+-----+------+
|first|second|
+-----+------+
|    1|     2|
|    3|     2|
|    4|     2|
|    5|     2|
|    7|     2|
+-----+------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass List\[String\] to function that takes f(args: String\*) scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258023/pass-liststring-to-function-that-takes-fargs-string-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `_*` for **varargs** in **Scala**, so you can do it by: `sc.parallelize(arr,2).toDF(colNames:_*)`