# scala.collection.Seq doesn't work on Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Using:

- Apache Spark 2.0.1
- Java 7

On the Apache Spark Java API documentation for the class DataSet appears an [example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#join(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset,%20scala.collection.Seq)) to use the method join using a scala.collection.Seq parameter to specify the columns names. But I'm not able to use it.
On the documentation they provide the following example:

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("user_id", "user_name"))
```

**Error: Can not find Symbol Method Seq(String)**

My Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import scala.collection.Seq;

public class UserProfiles {

public static void calcTopShopLookup() {
    Dataset<Row> udp = Spark.getDataFrameFromMySQL("my_schema","table_1");

    Dataset<Row> result = Spark.getSparkSession().table("table_2").join(udp,Seq("col_1","col_2"));
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060377/how-to-use-scala-varargs-from-java-code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Seq(x, y, ...)` is a Scala way to create sequence. Seq has it's companion object, which has apply method, which allows to not write `new` each time.

It should be possible to write:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
import scala.collection.Seq;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

Dataset<Row> result = Spark.getSparkSession().table("table_2").join(udp, JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(asList("col_1","col_2")));`
```

Or you can create own small method:

```
 public static <T> Seq<T> asSeq(T... values) {
        return JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(asList(values));
    }
```

Comment: @TzachZohar Yes, my mistake, I forgot that using companion object is not so easy ;) Please see edit

Comment: @TzachZohar worth noting that it works only if you import `scala.collection.immutable.Seq`, not `mutable` or the `scala.collection.Seq`.

Comment: @TzachZohar which version of Scala you're using? In my version, 2.11, I cannot do `new Seq("vaue")` as Seq is abstract - both `scala.collection.Seq` and immutable version

Comment: @T.Gawęda thank you very much!!! it works with your first advice, the second one from **TzachZohar** doesn't works, or at least, is not that easy cause the Seq class is abstract, and I don't want to implement all those methods.

Comment: Credits also for @Łukasz, he wrote his answer in the same time as I wrote my edit (first version was bad, I forgot one thing as he helped me). Thanks :)