# java, how to call UDF in spark 1.4.1

Tags: java, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

In spark 1.4.1, the parameter of callUdf method is

```
(String udfName, scala.collection.Seq<Column> cols)
```

There is no method that can act to column directly, like method in 1.5.1

```
callUDF(String udfName, Column col)
```

So how to call UDF in 1.4.1? Or how to change column type to

```
scala.collection.Seq<Column>
```

For example, these codes work in 1.6.1

```
sqlContext.udf().register("stringToLong", new UDF1<String, Long>() {

    @Override
    public Long call(String arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        IPTypeConvert itc = new IPTypeConvert();
        return itc.stringtoLong(arg0);
    }
}, DataTypes.LongType);
DataFrame interDF = initInterDF.withColumn("interIPInt", callUDF("stringToLong", initInterDF.col("interIP")));
```

How should I change the codes so that they can work in spark 1.4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert list to Seq[Column]:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
import scala.collection.Seq;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

DataFrame interDF = initInterDF.withColumn("interIPInt", 
    callUDF("stringToLong", JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(asList(initInterDF.col("interIP")))));
```

See more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741459/scala-collection-seq-doesnt-work-on-java/40741804#40741804) question

Comment: Forgive me, I am a rookie. Thank you very much!

Comment: @volity Relax :) I'm happy I have helped you :)