# How to create a custom Uniform Fan Out Shape in Akka through the Java library

Tags: java, stream, akka

So I am building an Akka custom component to learn the framework. I need to create a UnifromFanOut shape custom component. So I tried to extend the shape but the issue is how do I create the shape with 1 input and 3 outputs. The class requires a seq object which is a part of Scala but I am a bit confused on whether the whole shape itself is correct. I just started learning Akka so I can understand if my approach is wrong. Also I the purpose of the exercise was to create a custom component and I know I can get the logic done through GraphDSL but it needs to be a custom component. My question is how do I create this shape correctly. (the documentation isn't the best for custom components)

```
    public final Inlet<DeviceInfo> in = Inlet.create("Map.in");
    public final Outlet<DeviceInfo> temp_out = Outlet.create("Map.out");
    public final Outlet<DeviceInfo> humidity_out = Outlet.create("Map.out");
    public final Outlet<DeviceInfo> illumination_out = Outlet.create("Map.out");
    //Does not work
    private final UniformFanOutShape<DeviceInfo, DeviceInfo> shape = UniformFanOutShape.apply(in, Arrays.asList(temp_out, humidity_out));

    @Override
    public UniformFanOutShape<DeviceInfo, DeviceInfo> shape() {     
        return shape;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT]
TL;DR
You basically need to work around calling Scala vararg method from Java. You can do it like this using  `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer`

```
    ArrayBuffer<Outlet<DeviceInfo>> arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer<>();
    arrayBuffer.append(temp_out);
    arrayBuffer.append(humidity_out);
    arrayBuffer.append(illumination_out);

    final UniformFanOutShape<DeviceInfo, DeviceInfo> shape =
      UniformFanOutShape.apply(in, arrayBuffer.toSeq());
```

source: [How to use Scala varargs from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060377/how-to-use-scala-varargs-from-java-code)

[/EDIT]

> (the documentation isn't the best for custom components)

I disagree. The documentation is pretty comprehensive (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html)

You shouldn't extend `UniformFanOutShape<DeviceInfo, DeviceInfo>`, but rather `GraphStage<UniformFanOutShape<DeviceInfo, DeviceInfo>>`.

You then need to override two methods:

```
 public UniformFanOutShape<DeviceInfo, DeviceInfo> shape() {
    //implement
 }

 @Override
 public GraphStageLogic createLogic(Attributes inheritedAttributes) {
   //implement
 }
```

the documentation shows you how to create shapes and how to implement `GraphStageLogic` with detailed information about handling backpressure, etc.

The documentation shows examples for `SourceShape`, `SinkShape` and `FlowShape`. If you understand those examples, but need some more guidance you can look at the source code. In `akka.stream.scaladsl.Graph.scala` you can find implementation of all built in `GraphStage`s Akka Streams provide. For example `Broadcast` is an example of a `UniformFanOutShape` stage and this is how the code for it starts:

`final class Broadcast[T](val outputPorts: Int, val eagerCancel: Boolean) extends GraphStage[UniformFanOutShape[T, T]]`

The implementation is under 100 lines of code and follows the same pattern like the documentation shows. The code is Scala, because Akka is implemented in that language with a thin Java layer meant to be used from Java code. So for example there's also `akka.stream.javadsl.Graph.scala`, but you will see that the code there is delegating to implementations in `scaladsl` package. You will see that pattern all over Akka code. So in short you will need to understand a bit of scala to understand the implementation but in this case here it's very similar to what Java implementation could look like.